# JavaScript/Jquery nodes from ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to get the nodes of class "ms-qSuggest-listItem" from the id.

```
<div class="ms-qSuggest-list" id="ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList" style="width: 508px;">
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Everything</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Videos</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-hListItem">People</div>
    <div class="ms-qSuggest-listItem">Conversations</div>
</div>
```

I tried

```
var nodes = $get("ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList").class(ms-qSuggest-listItem);
```

If I wanna get the nodes from its direct class - here its working but I want to get it from the ID.

```
var nodes = $("div.ms-qSuggest-listItem");
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, the [`$.get` function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is used to retrieve data via an HTTP GET request - it doesn't deal with DOM elements in the way that you have used it in your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `id` in conjunction with the `class` name within the same selector like this:

```
var long_id = 'ctl00_ctl38_g....';
var nodes = $('#' + long_id + ' .ms-qSuggest-listItem');
```

Basically what is happening here is the selector is matching the id and then looking inside it's children for the specified class name.

A more explicit way of writing this would be to use the [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function on the parent node itself.

> **Description**: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
var long_id = 'ctl00_ctl38_g....';
var parent_node = $('#' + long_id);
var children_nodes = parent_node.find('.ms-qSuggest-listItem');
```

### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uf48wp63/1/)

Comment: length equal to 0 too

Comment: @user3674148 - The code I have provided *does* work. You can [see a live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uf48wp63/1/). Perhaps you have some spelling mistakes? Perhaps your `id` attribute changes so you'll have to make sure you have the correct `id`.

Answer (score 2):

All the below selectors will give you the matching nodes.

```
var nodes = $("#ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList").find('.ms-qSuggest-listItem');
```

**OR**

```
var nodes = $("#ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList .ms-qSuggest-listItem");
```

**OR**

```
var nodes = $(".ms-qSuggest-listItem", "#ctl00_ctl38_g_c60051d3_9564_459e_8a40_e91f8abf4dcf_csr_NavDropdownList");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fr2d9yv1/

Comment: I am getting length 0

Comment: Check the spellings of `id` and `class` are correct

Comment: Spellings are correct as I am getting the object instance however length count is still 0 (Tried your 3rd suggestion as well)...